# Is there a way to display webform submission based on element values?

Tags: 8, webforms

I create a webform in Drupal 8 with certain elements (first name, last name, email, phone, visible (Yes / No)).

I want to display the results of the webform based on the element (visible = Yes), so that other roles cannot see the results where visible = No.

How can I do that? How can I filter webform submissions based on element values?

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to do that without query submissions ?. A hook or the Webform interface.

Comment: Yes with Views, see my answer below. You then can replace the default results entity list with your own view.

Comment: You can also do this by adding a Relation to 'Webform submissions: Data' to your view. You have to specify the webform node id and the field you want to access the data from, and then that fields data becomes available in the filters section.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [Webform Views Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views). This module allows you to build a view of webform submissions. You then can use Views' filtering on elements values.

Unclear is where you want to display them. But with Webform Views Integration you can of course build a view page with an URL or view block as you need.

> Use Webform Views Integration module to expose Webform submissions to Views (Webform is a module for making forms and surveys in Drupal).